# como reduzir o tamanho do zip criado com php

Tags: php, arquivo-zip

como posso reduzir o tamanho de um arquivo `ZIP` criado com `PHP`. estou conseguindo zipá-lo mas o tamanho dele continua o mesmo como posso diminuir o tamanho dele.
por exemplo quero zipar um arquivo de `2MB` e quando zipar quero que o `ZIP` fique com menos de `1MB` ou ate mesmo um `1MB` como fazer isso?

meu codigo

```php
$zip = new ZipArchive();

if( $zip->open( 'teste/sample.zip' , ZipArchive::CREATE )  === true) {
    $zip->addFile(  'teste/arqtest.pdf' , 'arqtest.pdf' );

    $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: Arquivos mp3, jpg entre outros já otimizam a forma como armazenam a informação e, portanto, não há muito o que fazer.

Comment: Se fosse possível zipar e ter uma alta taxa de compressão independente do arquivo então poderiamos zipar um arquivo várias vezes e partir de um arquivo com varios gigabytes e terminar com um arquivo de 1MB.

Answer (score 2):

O algoritmo `zip` é fixo. Você não consegue ter uma compressão maior porque a taxa de compressão depende principalmente do tipo de dado que está sendo comprimido.

Por exemplo, você terá uma taxa de compressão muito boa ao comprimir um arquivo de texto contendo nada além de caracteres `A`, mas uma taxa de compressão irrelevante para um arquivo `mp3`, por exemplo.